# My query won't work properly in Laravel, but it works fine in Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

**My Problem**

I'm building a social network, and I want to select a list of "feed items" from a table (`feed_items`). A feed item can be a `status-update`, a `kiss`, or a `photo`, as specified in the `type` column.

If you're friends with someone, you can see any `status-update` or `photo` post by them as indicated by the `user_id` column.

You can only see kisses sent to you, the column representing that being `specific_user_id`.

**My Code**

I want to use Eloquent because I can use it to fetch relationships with each feed item. So below is my query code:

```
$items = FeedItems::where(function($query) use($connectionsString)
            {
                $query->whereRaw("(type = ? and specific_user_id = ?)", 
                [
                    "kiss",
                    Sentry::getUser()->id
                ])
                ->orWhere(function($query) use($connectionsString)
                    {
                        $query->whereRaw("(user_id in (?) and type != ?)",
                        [
                            "$connectionsString",
                            "kiss"
                        ]);
                    }
                );
            })
            ->whereNotIn("id", $hidden)
            ->with("user", "status", "photo")
            ->paginate(90);
```

When I run the code in Laravel, it only returns kisses. However, if I copy the query from the query log:

```
{
    "query": "select * from `feed_items` where ((type = ? and specific_user_id = ?) or ((user_id in (?) and type != ?))) and `id` not in (?) limit 90 offset 0",
    "bindings": [
        "kiss",
        "1",
        "354, 226, 391, 628, 411, 748, 678, 367, 739, 141, 129, 717, 586, 441, 657, 532, 444, 649, 648, 630, 132, 273, 477, 675, 69, 504, 621, 729, 606, 742, 124, 357, 168, 394, 115, 436, 748, 547, 628, 99, 202, 321, 243, 370, 130, 73, 535, 199, 471, 547, 736, 480, 715, 556, 697, 501, 118, 195, 220, 480, 24, 471, 348, 7, 625, 261, 220, 30, 357, 592, 435, 667, 439, 589, 198, 91, 565, 121, 210, 16, 465, 93, 628, 246, 709",
        "kiss",
        0
    ],
}
```

and adjust it to run in Sequel Pro:

```
select * from `feed_items` where ((type = 'kiss' and specific_user_id = 1) or ((user_id in (354, 226, 391, 628, 411, 748, 678, 367, 739, 141, 129, 717, 586, 441, 657, 532, 444, 649, 648, 630, 132, 273, 477, 675, 69, 504, 621, 729, 606, 742, 124, 357, 168, 394, 115, 436, 748, 547, 628, 99, 202, 321, 243, 370, 130, 73, 535, 199, 471, 547, 736, 480, 715, 556, 697, 501, 118, 195, 220, 480, 24, 471, 348, 7, 625, 261, 220, 30, 357, 592, 435, 667, 439, 589, 198, 91, 565, 121, 210, 16, 465, 93, 628, 246, 709) and type != 'kiss'))) and `id` not in (0) limit 90 offset 0;
```

I get kisses, status updates, and photos as I want.
[image: Query code run in Sequel Pro]

Can someone shed light on why this is happening, and perhaps offer an alternative solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query you're running with Laravel and the one you have in SequelPro are different, despite the difference is hardly noticeable at first glance.

This is what you need, definitely don't use those nested `whereRaw`s, because it doesn't make sense, and never pass bound string to `where in` (see below):

```
$connectionsArray; // array of user_id s
$userId = Sentry::getUser()->id;

$items = FeedItems::where(function($q) use ($connectionsArray, $userId)
{
  $q->where('type', 'kiss')
    ->where('specific_user_id', $userId)
    ->orWhereIn('user_id', $connectionsArray)
    ->where('type', '<>', 'kiss');
})
->whereNotIn("id", $hidden)
->with("user", "status", "photo")
->paginate(90);
```

And about that difference:

```
// SQL query:
SELECT ... WHERE ... OR user_id in (354, 226, ...) ...

// Laravel query:
SELECT ... WHERE ... OR user_id in ('354, 226, ...') ...
```

**That said, your joined ids were bound by PDO and treated as string, thus evaluated to 1.**

---

You could do this instead and this one would work as expected:

```
whereRaw("user_id in ({$connectionsString})")
```

but I'd rather not.

Comment: Well, that's much cleaner, and works great :) I didn't start off with all those nested `whereRaw`s, but I was trying different combinations, haha. Thank you!